# Can I get connect response if recipient signs one document and not other in an template?

Tags: docusignapi

I have one template which contains two documents. I send signature request using this template using rest api. I need to get connect response if recipient signs one document and not other document. Also I need to get connect response if he signs remaining document later sometime. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When the recipient opens the envelope, you will get a "delivered"  webhook / message.

When a recipient finishes signing all of the documents, you get the signed message.

It is impossible to "sign"  just part of the envelope since the "signing" happens when the signer clicks "finished" not when they sign a particular signing tab in a document.

Also, note that an earlier message can be skipped if a later message is generated right after the earlier one.

**Added**

You can watch the webhook messages come in by using the new [Beta DocuSign Recipe Tool](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python). It is available now in Python, it will be ported to other languages in the future.

In the tool, send an envelope, either embedded or email signing. Then click the button to watch the connect messages come in on another tab. You can see the "Delivered" message come in if you *open* (not sign) the envelope to sign.

If you open the envelope and then sign it right away, the "Delivered" webhook message will often be superseded by the "signed" message.